# colorControlNormal not setting toolbar back arrow color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-theme

I'm trying to change the color of my toolbar's back arrow to purple, but the color I set for the colorControlNormal attribute of my custom toolbar theme isn't working. The toolbar should be purple but it remains white.

I've checked all over my layout's xml and the app Manifest to see if my toolbar theme is being overidden somewhere but i don't see this.

What's the problem?

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/silver</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/roar_purple</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/customActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black_87_two</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/roar_purple</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/roar_purple</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp</item>
    </style>
...
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumEntryAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
...
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginSignupEnterPhoneActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login_enter_phone_num"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:parentActivityName="com.roarforgood.roar.PrivacyDisclaimerActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

Comment: I doubt that it can change the drawable's color, maybe it only works on a vector drawable. Try to import a purple chevron rather than a white one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename `ic_chevron_left_white_48dp` looks like the ones that Android Studio creates when you use the `New -> Image Asset` or `New -> Vector Asset` menu options.

If you used `Image Asset`, delete all of your files and start over with `Vector Asset`. If you used `Vector Asset` in the first place, ignore this bit.

When I generate a white chevron vector, it looks like this:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>

</vector>
```

To fix the problem, you need to do two things:

- Delete the `android:tint` attribute from the `<vector>` tag
- Change the `android:fillColor` attribute to `?attr/colorControlNormal` in the `<path>` tag

That should leave you with this:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
        android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>

</vector>
```

When I do this, and use styles like you posted, I correctly see my `colorControlNormal` for my chevron in the toolbar.

Comment: Great answer! I was using a vector asset, but the fillColor attribute wasn't set to colorControlNormal. Changing this fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: If the icon preview becomes invisible due to using ?attr/colorControlNormal you can add tools:fillColor="#FF000000" to make the preview black again

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

```
 <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/roar_purple</item>
 <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp</item> //delete this line
```

You only want show back arrow, so just do like this:

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```