# android - Change MaterialToolbar menu items icon color

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-xml, android-theme, material-components-android

Im currently creating an app, which has a `MaterialToolbar` widget. I want to set the icons color to white.
I tried following the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053619/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-icons-in-toolbar), however, it doesnt work. Adding `colorControlNormal` in styles.xml doesnt work.

This is my MaterialToolbar xml code:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:title="Revo"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_floatingsearchview"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

What can i do?

**EDIT, SOLUTION AND EXPLENATION**

Thanks everyone for the nice answers. I managed to find a solution, that will include both solutions, and another question.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328026/colorcontrolnormal-not-setting-toolbar-back-arrow-color) question, was asked why `colorControlNormal` doesnt work. The accepted answer says that in the vector lines, you have to change the value given to `android:fillColor`, and replace it with `?attr/colorControlNormal`. Doing this trick, item colorControlNormal, will control the desired icons color.

In the app **main** style, you need to put:

`<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>`

Then, in the desired icon, you need to put under `path`:

`android:fillColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"`

Thats it! Now the icons will get the color given to the colorControlNormal attribute!

Comment: Which icons are you referring? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074174/how-to-change-the-navigation-icon-color/58074791#58074791

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti im referring to the two icons on the right of the toolbar, contained in a menu xml file, named menu_floatingsearchview. Do i have to update the thread with the menu code?

Comment: Please write an answer to your question. It is easy to overlook an answer in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
        .../>
```

with:

```
<style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason this one doesnt seem to work. It is yet another method that is used by most dvelopers, proposed by many. But this one just doesnt work...

Comment: @Meltix what is your app theme? Are you using a Material Components theme?

Comment: This is my app theme:
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: @Meltix which version of material components are you using?

Comment: Im currently using the version 1.3.0 alpha 01, here's the line:
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

Comment: @Meltix Try to add in the `Toolbar`  layout: `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary`. Or in the themeOverlay `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/....</item>`

Comment: @Meltix sorry but I am unable to replicate your issue. Just tried also with 1.2.0-beta01 and it seems to work.

Comment: No worries. Maybe im doing something wrong. Thanks anyway!
I'll accept your answer as soon as i get these solutions working.

Comment: Hey! I updated the post with the solution of the problem!

Comment: The `<item name="colorOnPrimary">...</item>` part didn't work for me. Using `<item name="iconTint">...</item>` instead works.

Comment: @Robyer `colorOnPrimary` works if you are using a theme overlay (`android:theme`). `iconTint` instead works if your using a style (`style`). They are completely different.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I had it as `android:theme`, but I just realized the difference. The `colorOnPrimary` indeed changes the color of the toolbar's title and overflow menu icon itself, BUT it has no effect on icons of menu items inflated from the menu xml resource - their color is changed only by changing the `iconTint` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

That one bugged me a few days ago.
I ended up doing this:

1. set your desired color to a variable in `colors.xml`

   <color name="toolbarTextColor">#ffffff</color>
2. Then set this color **directly in the source of drawable**

   android:fillColor="@color/toolbarTextColor"
3. Also, use same variable when setting color of text in `MaterialToolbar`.

This way, you have icons always the same color as text, which is, I suppose, what you want. Otherwise, just use another variable.

Comment: Well, this definetly works! Im waiting some other responses before accepting your answer, thanks!